# Python multiprocessing clears list structure?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing script that looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

currentDepth = 1
maxDepth = 3
nodeList = []
auxList = []

def grow():
    global nodeList
    global auxList
    while(nodeList):
        print("Iterate on: " + str(nodeList))
        p.map(proc1, nodeList)
        print("Repopulating nodeList: " + str(nodeList) + " from auxList: " + str(auxList))   
        nodeList = list(auxList)

nodeList.append(seed)
p = Pool(8)
grow()
```

The `proc1` function calls a `proc2` function which looks like this:

```
def proc1(currentNode):
     val = int(currentNode.name)*2
     if (val not in visited):
         proc2(currentNode, val, currentNode.depth+1)

def proc2(currentNode, newVal, depth):
    global currentDepth
    global auxList
    print("Next node value: " str(newVal))
    print("Next node depth: " str(depth))
    nextNode = Tree(name='{}'.format(newVal))
    currentNode.add_child(nextNode)
    if depth > currentDepth:
        currentDepth = depth
        print("Current Depth updated: " + str(currentDepth))
        print("Maximum Depth: " + str(maxDepth))
    if depth < maxDepth:
        print("Appending to aux: " + str(nextNode.name)
        auxList.append(nextNode)
        print("auxList: " + str(auxList))
```

`proc2` successfully appends to the `auxList`, which in turn should repopulate the nodeList every iteration up to a certain depth. The output of the prints looks like this:

```
Iterate on: [Tree node '2' (0x7f3537cd61d)]
Next node value: 4
Node depth: 2
Current Depth updated: 2
Maximum Depth: 3
Appending to aux: 4
auxList: [Tree node '4' (0x7f79abec191)]
Repopulating nodeList: [Tree node '2' (0x7f79ac3171d)] from auxList: []
```

Everything is compiling properly, so why is `auxList` missing its entry? I have some suspicions about the asynchronous execution and my usage of globals but I can't figure out what the problem is. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Multiprocessing does not magically share variables.  Every process in the pool has its own copy of `auxList` (and every other variable for that matter). `auxList.append()` from any of the pool processes does not change `auxList` in the main process.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, I really appreciate the help! Time to go refactor

Comment: @PedroUrbina threads share memory, processes don't.